# Genymotion plugin no longer present in Android Studio plugins Marketplace in the latest Android Studio version 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, repository, genymotion

I had Genymotion plugin available in Android Studio plugins earlier. But after release of version 4.1.1 the plugin is missing from Marketplace.

[image]

I go to File --> Settings --> Plugins

Many plugins are displayed here. But when I type Genymotion in search box, it says - nothing found

How do I install the Genymotion plugin now.

I don't intend to manually download the plugin and install it from disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genymotion Android plugin is not available from Android Studio marketplace with ver. 4.1.1 and above. You **have to** install it manually from https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/ or downgrade to a lower version of Android Studio.